# remove rows that a particular column has NA

Tags: r, rows, na

I want to remove rows in the dataset where a column 'ABC' contains NA,

so I write:

```
dataset = dataset[dataset$ABC !='NA',]
```

the result:

instead of removing those rows that column 'ABC' is NA, it changes every column of those rows to NA

Example:

```
row     AAA   BBB   ABC
1        3     2     1
2        3     3     NA
3        1     2     3
```

result:

```
row     AAA   BBB   ABC
1        3     2     1
2        NA    NA    NA
3        1     2     3
```

where am I wrong? Thanks

Comment: `data[!is.na(data$ABC),]`  `NA` is not a character string in your data, like you're using it.

Comment: Use `is.na` : `dataset[!is.na(dataset$ABC),]`

Comment: For just a single column, use `dataset = dataset[!is.na(dataset$ABC ),]`. The `NA` value is a special one. To test use `is.na()` rather than `!="NA"`

Comment: I like the diagonal nature of our three comments.